# Error in setting up icinga_web. Table doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, database-connection, monitoring, nagios

I'm trying to setup icinga-web interface for monitoring servers. I have it installed and done with all troubleshooting mentioned here -

https://wiki.icinga.org/display/testing/Icinga+Web+Testing

But, I'm getting this error while accessing icinga-web interface -

Uncaught Doctrine_Connection_Mysql_Exception thrown:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'icinga_web.nsm_session' doesn't exist

Looking into databases, nsm_session table is present in "icinga" database and not "icinga_web". Is there any configuration that I am missing?  Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 2):

Likely you mixed your database setup.

- 'icinga' is the default database for the idoutils database backend, letting icinga config/status/historical write into it
- 'icinga_web' is a seperate database (and schema) which is only for icinga web's session, internal auth, etc information

It seems that the icinga_web db schema was imported into the 'icinga' database, and now the default settings of your icinga web installation point to the incorrect location.

There's two possibilities here:

- clean the 'icinga' database from the faulty tables (look into icinga-web-src/etc/schema/mysql.sql to see which tables are created) and create the database 'icinga_web' and import the schema (see the docs on how to achieve that)
- or work with the existing 'icinga' database, but update your icinga web databases.xml configuration - the dsn part for the icinga_web parts must bei changed to select the correct database 'icinga' then. http://docs.icinga.org/latest/en/icinga-web-config.html#configweb-databases

I would go with the clean and seperate way, makes debugging and resolving errors easier, so 1)

note: if you did install via package manager, i.e. apt, run "dpkg-reconfigure " for invoke the database configuration assistant.